# How can I insert an arrow from one word to another?

Tags: tables, arrows

I'm doing a table using tabular and I am trying to write "ATP->AMP" but I can't quite figure out how to insert the arrow. I've looked and searched and I haven't found anything that can help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply `ATP $ \to$  AMP` or `ATP \textrightarrow\ AMP`? (The latter requires `textcomp` with a non-up-to-date installation.) Or should the arrow be the column separator? Please provide some more context...

Comment: @campa That did exactly what I needed!!! Thank you so much! Such a simple fix, I was overthinking it!

Comment: @campa yes it does answer my question. Thank you for your help.